# Robocopy - Copy File If New and Rename

Tags: robocopy

I have a single backup file that gets created hourly, lets call it AUGUST.backup,
I wish to create a Robocopy script that when ran will check the backup folder for new files, and if there is a new file, it will rename it to latest.backup and move it to a mapped drive. It must also overwrite the previous latest.backup file in the mapped drive folder.

Comment: What is the question? What problems do you have with creating such a script?

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy cannot do all this, so you are probably looking for a script.

A simple batch script skeleton, which you can complete and put in a `.bat`
file, is as follows:

```
loop:
fc /b file1 file2 > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  del /q file2.backup
  ren file2 file2.backup
  robocopy file1 file2
)
timeout 3600
goto loop
```